# req.body is undefined in Node.js even though when I log req it shows the body and its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

Good Evening,
I am trying to log the req.body to the console, but it says that it is undefined even though when I do console.log(req) the body and its contents show up. I am trying to make a Twilio text app. I am lost, I am not sure it says the body is undefined even though it is defined. Any guidance is appreciated.

```js
/* Nodejs index.js */
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const indexRouter = require('./routes/index-router');


/* View Engine */
const ejs = require('ejs');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.use('/', indexRouter);




app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(404);
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Twilio app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})

/* Index Router */
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use(bodyParser.json());


require('dotenv').config();

var accountSid = process.env.ACCOUNT_SID; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
var authToken = process.env.AUTH_TOKEN;   // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

var twilio = require('twilio');
var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken); 


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index')  
});


  /*Twilio */
router.post('/', (res, req) => {
     /* client.messages.create({
        body: `${req.body.text}`,
        to: '+17185412931',  // Text this number
        from: '+12058946009' // From a valid Twilio number
    })
        .then((message) => console.log(message.sid)); */
        console.log(req);
}) 

module.exports = router;


/*  AJAX Request */






$('#text').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const message = $("#message").val();


    const data = {
        message: message,
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "/", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType: "json", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        contentType: "application/json", // Need this to send proper data to server
        data: JSON.stringify(data), //Form variables
        success: function (sucess) {
            alert("Text has sent");

        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BootStrap Start</title>
   
        <!-- Bootstrap Link -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <header>
        <!-- Fixed navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
                aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
<!--
    <div class="container main-content">
        <div class="row message" id="message-row">
           
        </div>
        
        <div class="row text" id="text-row">
            <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
            <input class="form-control btn" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
        </div>
    --> 
        <div class="row contact-row" id="contact-row-id">
            <div class="col-xs col-sm col-md col-lg col-xl contact-container" id="contact-container-id">
                <div class="form" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="3000" data-aos-easing="linear">
                    <form method="POST" action="/text" id="text" class="text">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">text </label>
                            <br>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="message" id="message" required>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control btn" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
        
        
        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQUERY -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="/javascripts/ajax.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@augdog97,

The req/res are in wrong positions. Change `(res, req)` to `(req, res)`

Comment: holy moly! that is so embarrassing, thank you! Gotta love syntax errors haha